# Should I use "is" or "are"?

Tags: translation

I am supposed to make a translation for a session to be submitted, but I'm stumbled upon this. We say "content is fed from a centralised location", right? How about "hundreds of websites' content"? Is it still "is", or is it now "are"?

Thank you in advanced :)
K.

Comment: [dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/content?q=content#content-2) can be such useful tools!

Comment: *content* is singular. Any other issues with it?

Comment: "hundreds of websites' content".  Websites is already plural, so only add an apostrophe ', not 's.

Comment: @Kris, I don't see how this was hold as off-topic. I thought this was the SE site for English question and I asked an English question

Comment: Anything that can be found in a dictionary is off-topic on ELU. That's how. HTH.

Answer (score 9):

In English, non-count nouns take the singular verb. “Content” is a non-count noun.

If you would say this:

> The content of hundreds of websites is ...

Then you would say this:

> Hundreds of websites' content is ...

The **is** is always referring to *content*, which is singular.

Answer (score 0):

Content, in this perspective, may mean two different things.

> Content, when it means "information made available by the website", is singular, and thus will take "is". E.g.: Hundreds of websites' content is.. (as quoted by @RiMMER)
>
> Content, when it means "the things that are held or included in something", is plural, and thus takes "are". E.g.: The contents of these websites are astounding.

But, when referring to websites, people generally use the singular content, presuming that you are talking about the information and not a list of items.

Answer (score 0):

"Content" is not a countable noun; you can't say *one content, *two contents, etc.  It would be like referring to "my luggages."

For this reason, you should stick with singular verbs even when referring to content from disparate sources.